# Redirect in PHP with condition

Tags: php, indexing, redirect

How to redirect user when the user is logged in?

1. User visits homepage, it loads custom PHP script at `http://www.domain.com/index.php`
2. Index.php script - Verifies user is logged in with `Get http://panel.domain.com/CheckUserLogin.aspx`

   `CheckUserLogin.aspx` response with text "True" when the current user is logged in, otherwise  "False"
3. If True redirect to `https://panel.domain.com` else redirect to `http://www.domain.com/cms`

Comment: What is your question?  How do to an `if` statement?  How to redirect?  Or how to get the contents of a resource at a specific URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using PHP, you could do this on the client-side with JavaScript. Using jQuery, something like this:

```js
$.ajax("CheckUserLogin.asxp", {dataType: "text"}).then(function(value) {
    if (value == "True") {
        window.location = "https://panel.domain.com";
    } else {
        window.location = "http://www.domain.com/cms";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically PHP won't be able to get the text returned by the ASP page as both scripts are processed server side. The best way should be to do redirect from the ASPX instead of index.php. However if you have no way to change the ASP code, you could try doing a php cURL request passing the user's cookies to the asp server and fetching the results doing an `if` statement.